ESLint expects a callback returned at end of arrow function
I have this array:
var json = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "firstName": "Paul",
      "lastName": "Carr",
      "company": "Foo"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "firstName": "Mary",
      "lastName": "Menan",
      "company": "Foo"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "firstName": "Donal",
      "lastName": "Carr",
      "company": "Bar"
    }
  ];

and this checkbox code:
<div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" checked={isChecked} onChange={checkHandler} />
      <p>{isChecked ? json.map(j => <div>{j.id}, {j.firstName}, {j.lastName}, {j.company}</div>) : json.map(k => {
        if(k.company !== "Bar") {
          <div>{k.id}, {k.firstName}, {k.lastName}, {k.company}</div>
        }
      })}</p>
    </div>
  )

If the box is checked I want the entire array printed. If not, only the people who are not in company Foo should be printed. However, when I run the code I get:
src/App.js
  Line 44:111:  Array.prototype.map() expects a value to be returned at the end of arrow function  array-callback-return

My code works but I'm not sure how I fix it so I don't get the lint warning. What should it look like?

What if k.company === "Bar"? Probably you should filter them out. "expects a callback returned" - no, it "expects a value to be returned", from the callback. Look at the documented examples.

You need to use the return keyword when defining a function with braces

"My code works" although map returns an array only containing undefineds? Are you sure?

It expects something to be returned from the map function.
Also, you need to set a key value when rendering multiple items.See why here
Also, you should filter the items based on company iso using the IF
Code should look something like this
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    id="checkbox"
    checked={isChecked}
    onChange={checkHandler}
  />
  <p>
    {isChecked ? (
      json.map(j => (
        <div key={j.id}>
          {j.id}, {j.firstName}, {j.lastName}, {j.company}
        </div>
      ))
    ) : (
      json
        .filter(k => k.company !== "Bar")
        .map(k => (
          <div key={k.id}>
            {k.id}, {k.firstName}, {k.lastName}, {k.company}
          </div>
        ))
    )}
  </p>
</div>

Also, I would suggest you extract the jsx for 1 element into a separate component and use that. Something like
const Item = ({ data }) => (
  <div key={data.id}>
    {data.id}, {data.firstName}, {data.lastName}, {data.company}
  </div>
);

And in your parent component use
....
<Item key={j.id} data={j} /> and <Item key={k.id} data={k} />
...

